# Modifying the appearance of gvim

Tags: gvim

I wanted to set the color scheme of gvim to 'evening' and have line numbers displayed everytime I start. But I can't find the right .gvimrc file and how can I set these default settings. Help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That should be in the .vimrc file in your home directory (if you have none, just create one with that name), the .gvimrc is typically for things that rely on gvim, like say, hiding the menu bar or toolbar would go there, all vim behavior itself goes into .vimrc

Anyway both should be placed in your home directory, and gvim will load both .vimrc and then .gvimrc afterwards when starting.

To get the evening scheme and numbers working, add this to your .vimrc

```
" look & feel
syntax on
set background=dark
colorscheme evening

" for showing line numbers
set number
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm all set!